# How to get a list of pods that have status Running without resorting to external commands?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to get a list of pods that have status `Running` from `kubectl`?

Using an external command it would be:

`kubectl get pods | grep Running`

Can I ask this from `kubectl` directly instead of string matching with grep or awk?

Comment: No, but writing a python script is easy. I can provide an example if you are interested.

Comment: No, thanks I am already able to script this, I am asking this question because I am wondering whether I am missing out on an obvious feature in kubectl that I am currently unaware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a golang template: 
`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{if eq (.status.phase) ("Running")}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}{{end}}'`
 
Of course `{{.metadata.name}}` can be replaced or extended with any informations you need.